# JSON format indent applicable inside each record using PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have 2 sample JSON record, I want to remove the indent using python.
Using this syntax(line.replace(" ", "")) I removed all indent.
But issue is all records come as one record.
Expectation is each record should come in one line.
pls guide me

```
{
    "device_model": "TITAN",
    "enb_locan": {
        "coordinates": [
            -900011,
            900.87
        ],
        "crs": {
            "properties": {
                "name": "EPSG:4326"
            },
            "type": "name"
        },
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "enb_order_distance": 25,
    "trans_dt": "2024-01-11"
}
{
    "device_model": "TITAN2222",
    "enb_locan": {
        "coordinates": [
            -900011,
            900.87
        ],
        "crs": {
            "properties": {
                "name": "EPSG:4326"
            },
            "type": "name"
        },
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "enb_order_distance": 29,
    "trans_dt": "2024-01-11"
}
```

code using

```
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
    text = IOUtils.readLines(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    for line in text:
        output = line.replace(" ", "")
        outputStream.write(output)
```

Comment: What's the point?  JSON absolutely does not care about whitespace.  Why waste time with this?  And, as a side note, the excellent command line tool `jq` can do this with no programming required.

Comment: And, as a second note, what you have there is not valid JSON.  If you want those separated, you'll have to detect the `"}"` in column 1.

Comment: _But issue is all records come as one record_ We don't know what this means.  Please show us the actual code and show us the output that is all "one record".

Comment: Self duplicate of [Using Python remove indentation in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77874702/using-python-remove-indentation-in-json)

Comment: You added both [tag:python-3.x] and [tag:python-2.7] tags again. Which are you actually using?

Comment: Just getting rid of indentations seems useless. It won't make it a singe line.

Comment: `line.replace(" ", "")` will also replace space inside JSON strings, which will mange the data.

Comment: {"device_model":"TITAN|XCI55AXTITAN2GATEWAY5GF","enb_location":{"coordinates":[-190.46,138.497],"crs":{"properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"},"type":"name"},"type":"Point"},"enb_distance":75,"trans_dt":"24-01-14"}{"device_model":"TITAN22222|XCI55AXTITAN2GATEWAY5GF","enb_location":{"coordinates":[-11.462333,11.497778],"crs":{"properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"},"type":"name"},"type":"Point"},"enb_order_distance":75,"trans_dt":"2024-01-14"}

Comment: getting the result as all in one record

Comment: next record should come in next line

Comment: Sounds like OP wants [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format, where each complete JSON record is on a single line terminated by a newline.

Below is a crude nested curly brace counter to collect complete records and re-write as a single line.  It expects the JSON to start with a curly brace and that each record is valid.  It would need to be extended to count other types of initial JSON data such as `[]` if the JSON started differently.

```py
import io
import json
import sys

data = '''\
{
    "device_model": "TITAN",
    "enb_locan": {
        "coordinates": [
            -900011,
            900.87
        ],
        "crs": {
            "properties": {
                "name": "EPSG:4326"
            },
            "type": "name"
        },
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "enb_order_distance": 25,
    "trans_dt": "2024-01-11"
}
{
    "device_model": "TITAN2222",
    "enb_locan": {
        "coordinates": [
            -900011,
            900.87
        ],
        "crs": {
            "properties": {
                "name": "EPSG:4326"
            },
            "type": "name"
        },
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "enb_order_distance": 29,
    "trans_dt": "2024-01-11"
}
'''

# Could read from file as well.
with io.StringIO(data) as f:
    record = []
    nested = 0
    while c := f.read(1):  # read and store characters
        record.append(c)
        if c == '{':       # keep track of nesting
            nested += 1
        if c == '}':
            nested -= 1
        if nested == 0:    # Once nested returns to zero, we have a full record
            data = ''.join(record).strip()  # build record and remove whitespace before and after
            if data:  # load the record and dump again without indentation
                print(json.dumps(json.loads(data)), file=sys.stdout)  # could print to a file.
                record = []
```

Output:

```json
{"device_model": "TITAN", "enb_locan": {"coordinates": [-900011, 900.87], "crs": {"properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}, "type": "name"}, "type": "Point"}, "enb_order_distance": 25, "trans_dt": "2024-01-11"}
{"device_model": "TITAN2222", "enb_locan": {"coordinates": [-900011, 900.87], "crs": {"properties": {"name": "EPSG:4326"}, "type": "name"}, "type": "Point"}, "enb_order_distance": 29, "trans_dt": "2024-01-11"}
```